# Intermediate value existence: $f''(\xi)-f(\xi)(1+2\cot^2\xi)=0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> Let $f$ be twice continuouly differentiable on $[0,\pi]$. $f(0)f(\pi)<0$. Show that there exists $\xi\in(0,\pi)$, such that $f''(\xi)-f(\xi)(1+2\cot^2\xi)=0$

I do not whether the problem is right, which is recalled by my classmate. Clearly, some zero of $f$ exists. $\cot\xi$ where to stand? Of course, is should not be $\pi/2$.

Comment: Have you tried using the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: @TobyMak Yes. But $f''$, not $f'$. I could not find such a $F$ such that $F'(x)=$ the form states.

Comment: @TobyMak Could you give some hints?

Comment: I don't have any; I was just seeing if you had tried something like that. Given the daily patterns of activity on this site, it's likely that you'll see more activity when people start to wake up US time.

Comment: @TobyMak How about multiplying by $f'$ on both sides? What to do then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question from IMC2013,It can help you solve your question.
[image: IMC2013]

Answer (score 0):

> Solve $y''=y(1+2\cot^2x)$

Solution: Let $\cos x=t$, we have $x=\arccos t\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

$$\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}=-\sqrt{1-t^2},\quad \frac{\mathrm d^2 t}{\mathrm dx^2}=-t,\quad \cot^2x=\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}=\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}$$

so

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}=-\sqrt{1-t^2}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\bigg(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}\bigg)=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d^2 t}{\mathrm dx^2}+\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}=-t\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}+(1-t^2)\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}$$

we get

$$(1-t^2)\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}-t\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=y\bigg(1+\frac{2t^2}{1-t^2}\bigg)$$

$$\Rightarrow\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}-\frac{t}{1-t^2}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{1+t^2}{(1-t^2)^2}y$$

Since

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\bigg(\frac{\mathrm dt}{1-t^2}\bigg)=\frac{1+t^2}{(1-t^2)^2}$$

so

$$\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}=\frac{1+t^2}{(1-t^2)^2}y+\frac{t}{1-t^2}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\bigg(\frac{t}{1-t^2}y\bigg)$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{t}{1-t^2}y+C_1$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\big(y\sqrt{1-t^2}\big)=-C_1\sqrt{1-t^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow y\sqrt{1-t^2}=\frac{1}{2}\big(-t\sqrt{1-t^2}+\arccos t\big)C_1+C_2$$

Finally,

$$y=C_1\bigg(\frac{x}{\sin x}-\cos x\bigg)+C_2\csc x$$

> Let $f$ be twice continuouly differentiable on $[0,\pi]$. $f(0)f(\pi)<0$. Show that there exists $\xi\in(0,\pi)$, such that $f''(\xi)-f(\xi)(1+2\cot^2\xi)=0$

Proof:

$$f''(\xi)-f(\xi)(1+2\cot^2\xi)=0 \Rightarrow y''=y(1+2\cot^2x)$$

Derivation

$$y=C_1\bigg(\frac{x}{\sin x}-\cos x\bigg)+C_2\csc x$$

$$\Rightarrow y'=C_1\bigg(\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{\sin^2x}+\sin x\bigg)-C_2\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}$$

Since

$$y\cos x=C_1\bigg(\frac{x\cos x}{\sin x}-\cos^2x\bigg)+C_2\cot x$$

$$y'\sin x=C_1\bigg(\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{\sin x}+\sin^2x\bigg)-C_2\cot x$$

Add

$$y\cos x+y'\sin x=2C_1\sin^2x\Rightarrow \frac{y\cos x+y'\sin x}{\sin^2x}=2C_1$$

Now consider the function

$$h(x)=\frac{f(x)\cos x+f'(x)\sin x}{\sin^2x}$$

$f(0)f(\pi)<0\Rightarrow\exists\xi_0\in(0,\pi)$, s.t. $f(\xi_0)=0$. Let $g(x)=f(x)\sin x$,

$$g(0)=g(\xi_0)=g(\pi)=0$$

Rolle’s theorem, we have $g'(\xi_1)=g'(\xi_2)=0\Rightarrow h(\xi_1)=h(\xi_2)=0$, Rolle’s theorem,  there exist $\xi\in(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ for which

$$h'(\xi)=\frac{f''(\xi)-f(x)(1+2\cot^2\xi)}{\sin\xi}=0$$